# How to setup cookieless domain in Lighttpd?

Tags: web-services, system-administration, lighttpd

I want to setup domain with disabled cookies, to serve static content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't set a cookie on your domain then. Seriously. That's all you have to do.

Just use a subdomain, and make sure you don't hit whatever your scripting solution is (php, python, whatever) anywhere on that domain. Also, make sure you don't have any lighty modules enabled that cause cookie creation (I'm not sure if there are any or not, but best to check).